# sendFile using nodejs not work

Tags: node.js

Couldn't make it work by sending the enterprise.html file using node+express
Below is the code in apps.js and in the public/html folder has enterprise.html. 
Have I done something wrong in this code.

```
var http = require('http'); //add the http module
var myServer = http.createServer(function(res, res) {
  // res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
  // res.write("<b>Hello</b> World");
  // res.sendFile(html/tenants.html);
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/html/enterprise.html');
  res.end();
}); //create a server

myServer.listen(3000);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/html/enterprise.html');
});
```

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

I think `app` is express. Simply try to use 
 
`app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.render(__dirname + '/html/enterprise.html');
 });`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it doesn't look like you've set up your server correctly. Right now you have created a webserver using the `http`method that comes packaged with node. If you'd like to use express, you need to instantiate it differently. Try this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();


app.listen(3000, function() {

  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));

});
```

And then you can listen for requests using the `app` variable.

```
app.get('/', function( req, res) {});
```

Documentation:

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var path = require('path'); 
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('output.xlsx'));
```